# How to automate daily scripting process and backup result to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012, excel-automation

I'm using SSMS 2012. I'm running set of SQL scripts on a remote desktop on a daily basis and backing up the data to an Excel spreadsheet.

I would like to automate the process where the SQL scripts are executed automatically and the results are backed up to an separate Excel sheets daily. How can I automate this?

Comment: Could you explain further about SSIS? I'm new to SQL server

Comment: SSIS is a big subject and this is a broad topic.   Google SSIS Tutorials to start learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use SQL Server Management Studio Select the database that contains the table that is the target.

2) Right Click and select Import Data. Finish the GUI and save the generated SSIS package on the file system.

3) Execute the SSIS package generated in step 2 using the dtexec command.

4) Use the built in 'at' command (Windows scheduler) or Task Scheduler to execute the package every day.